# Listing shared drives in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I'd like to list the Google Drive shared drives under my account. I'm using their [Drives: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list) API to do so. Running it in the console succeeds but gives me an empty list of drives, and I can't find any clues as to why.

I looked at their docs for [implementing shared drive support](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives) but none of it's relevant to listing drives.

Things I've checked:

- I'm logged into the account I think I am. I used the [about API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about) to confirm.
- I've granted the requisite scope to the console app ("Google APIs Explorer" has scope "View and manage metadata of files in your Google Drive")
- I have a folder shared with me -- under "Shared with me" in google drive I see the folder. Its details list its type as Google Drive Folder. It is owned by someone else but I have permission to add/delete files there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't confuse shared drives with shared folders

- A shared drive is something that is being created from the UI by clicking on `Shared drives-> New shared drive...` or programmaticaly with [Drives:Create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/create)
- A shared folder is a folder that is either on a user's private drive or a shared drive where you are not a member and only a specific folder (rather than the whole drive) has been shared with you by changing the sharing permissions.

**Conclusion: You cannot retrieve  folders that have been shread with you with the `Drives:list` method.**

To retrieve folders that have been shared with you, you need to

- use the method [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- set `includeItemsFromAllDrives` and `supportsAllDrives` to `true`
- You can set the [`q` parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files?authuser=1) to `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` to narrow down results.

Comment: Aaaaah! That set me straight. Thanks for clarifying the distinction for me.